# Difficulty joining layers in ARCGIS: Always asked to define projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, layers

Having followed manual instructions I am experiencing problems joining data to a map. What I have is a UK Districts shapefile and imported data with my coordinate data in it.

This coordinate data I produced in excel by assigning centroids to each district.
On advice I imported my excel file as a Personal geodatabase(.mdb) instead because apparently([ArcGis Join Data CSV Problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120961/arcgis-join-data-csv-problem)) ARCGIS treats this better but I still cannot fully merge layers.

The coordinates to 'map' onto my map  correctly - see image - but the two layers are not joined. I have the error that I need to define a projection. I try to do this through the ARC Toolbox but it still says unknown coordinate system in properties. I then add Join/Relate from the properties window but get another error message.

What Can I do to diagnose the problem here? I've been stuck for so long!

[image]

Comment: When you import your table into the ArcMap and display the XY coordinates, you should have set the CRS then.

Comment: Thanks @MacroZED - when I first go to display XY data and specify this it says 'Table specified does not have an object ID field so I won't be able to define Relates. Coudl this be the problem?

Comment: No it shouldnt be. I would try using your excel spreadsheet (.xls) as the source of your Lat/Long data. Go to "Add data" > Excel Spreadsheet. Once its been added to your map window, right click the spreadsheet and "Display X/Y data". Select your lat longs, and the reference system. Once the temporary point data is displayed, make sure you finalise it by exporting as shapefile or feature class in GDB. Try that.

Comment: No, unfortunately no luck. Even R has never caused me this many difficulties and I took care to make sure the dataset was properly cleaned, labelled and presented.

Comment: Add a screenshot of your excel spreadsheet please? Are your coordinates in decimal degrees?

Comment: Thank you, screenshot added. I'm going to be honest, I don't particularly understand my coordinate system - it seemed to detect it as national grid ?

Comment: Ok. the coordinates are in meters, which is British National Grid. These must be converted into Decimal Degrees before you can import into ArcMap and covert to a point dataset. Use http://gridreferencefinder.com/batchConvert/batchConvert.php to batch process.

Comment: Holy Moly! Ok, thank you so much, I have converted my coordinates as suggested into Degrees Decimal. ARCGIS offers loads of possible systems so I went for Geographic Cordinate Systems/World/W1984. However, does this mean I would also have to change (somehow) the coordinate systems inherent in my shapefile? I think the shapefile I am using goes by british National Grid as well. Thanks!!!

Comment: I have put an explanation below as the answer. if it worked for you, please mark as answered to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

The coordinate system within the spreadsheet is in British National Grid. These will need to be converted into Decimal Degrees before you can import them into ArcMap. Use http://gridreferencefinder.com/batchConvert/batchConvert.php to batch convert.

Once you have the new coordinates, import your excel spreadsheet (.xls) into ArcMap. 
Go to "Add data" > Excel Spreadsheet. Once its been added to your map window, right click the spreadsheet and "Display X/Y data". 
Select your lat longs, and the reference system, usually WGS84. Once the temporary point data is displayed, make sure you finalise it by exporting as shapefile or feature class in GDB.

If you other shapefile is using BNG, you can use the "Project" tool to convert these into WGS84.

Comment: I just read my shapefile into R to check its coordinate type and saw that its in just one column and basically two combined strings  (please see image above). How is it even able to read that at all as a meaningful shape and any ideas how to rectify? Thanks, super helpful.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean. It might just be a text formatting issue. However this is a different question all together, so please mark this as complete and ask another question on the stack exchange.